# Shopify - Product price starting "From"

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm wondering how to put "from" before the product price in Shopify.

I have product variants with different prices, that's why I want to setup a "From" before the cheapest variant price.

How can I do it? I can't find any way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
{% if product.price_varies %}
    From {{ product.price | money }}
{% else %}
    {{ product.price | money }}
{% endif %}
```

Documentation: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product#product-price_varies